# Issue in Bootstrap Accordion Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

FIRST OF ALL- SO SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

I have added accordion. It should be working as toogle. 
My code works like this

1. when you click on the title, it expands
2. when you click on the title again, it collapse
3. If I click on 2nd title, it opens but the first one remains OPEN. I want it to be closed once I expand any other one.

Here is my code. I am using Bootstrap 3

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion2" >
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading headding_new" style="height:58px;">
                <a class="accordion-toggle toggle_font" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne" >
                </a>
            </div>



            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">

                <div class="accordion-inner" style="width:83%; border:1px solid #aedddf;background: #f2f9fa;margin-left: 20px;height: 191px;margin-top: -4px;text-align:center;" >
                </br>
                    <img src="css/style/img/im2/351.png"/>
                    <div class=" chak_1" style="width:82%;border:2px solid #b31a1a;background:#fff;margin: auto;margin-top: 10px;padding: 20px;a">
                        <input type='checkbox' class="always" name="q1" value="1"onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<img src=css/style/img/im2/390.png/> &nbsp  ut sit veniam nulla laboris elit, cillum in velit. Do, cillum non cupidatat adipisicing eu, officia, id, velit minim ea reprehenderit est cillum. '" id="thing-1" /><label class="" for="thing-1" > </b></label>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!------------------------ 2 -----------------------------------> 


        <div class="accordion-group" style="">
            <div class="accordion-heading1 headding_new" style="height:58px;">
                <a class="accordion-toggle1 toggle_font" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <div class="accordion-inner" style="width:83%; border:1px solid #aedddf;background: #f2f9fa;margin-left: 20px;height: 191px;margin-top: -4px" style="text-align:center;">
                    </br>
                    <center> <img src="css/style/img/im2/350.png"/></center>

                     <div class=" chak_1"style="width:82%;border:2px solid #b31a1a;background:#fff;margin: auto;margin-top: 10px;padding: 20px;text-align: center" >
                        <input type='checkbox' class="always2" name="q2" value="2"onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<img src=css/style/img/im2/390.png/> &nbsp  Sit minim fugiat laboris labore ut amet ut. Adipisicing in mollit aliquip ex voluptate ex    '"    id="thing-2" /><label class="" for="thing-2" > </b></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<div class="bs-example">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```